# Add Muscles to my Tata Nano Car

Tags: car, tuning

Any Suggestions for Tuning my Tata Nano car into getting a muscle look and also an increase in power??.. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your car's engine is too tiny to bother with making it stronger. You're going to pay lots of money for very little increase in performance. It would be cheaper to trade your car in and buy something faster.

But if you insist, do the following:

1. Get an uprated clutch.
2. Get a set of 15 inch wheels.
3. install larger brake rotors.
4. get coilover suspension.
5. install a set of forged pistons.
6. install a stronger fuel pump.
7. install bigger fuel injectors.
8. install a Garrett GT12 turbo and intercooler.
9. install a full turbo back exhaust.
10. have your engine management updated.

All this will ensure your car looks the part and handle the upgraded performance. You'll probably get an extra 30kw (40hp) and a much smoother ride.

Answer (score 1):

I looked on [this website](http://www.examiner.com/article/tata-nano-performance-parts) which says since the Nano is almost a duplicate of the Smart Car found here in the States, fitting a Hayabusa engine into your Nano may be possible. Think about 200hp (as compared to the 39hp stock) in your Nano and you get the idea. Here are some points the website says:

> - Reduce air intake restriction by replacing duct work up to throttle body and using a high flow air filter element. Port and polish the throttle body to make it smooth. By gasket matching and polishing as much intake and exhaust contact surface as possible, you'll make gains.
> - Remove emissions equipment.
> - Port exhaust heads and OEM exhaust manifold.
> - Thermal wrap exhaust.
> - Silicon coolant lines wrapped in exhaust wrap.
> - External oil cooler.
> - Lower suspension by heating springs with torch and compressing, or by cutting. A good way to do this is have someone sit on the car while you heat the spring with a torch. If done right, it will lower the vehicle. Alternatively, you could check out Smart car strut assemblies and see if they will swap. Buy OEM Smart car parts at LKQ by clicking here.
> - Forced induction of various types. Be sure to upgrade fuel system and get a wide band air to fuel ratio gauge like AEM UEGO. Be sure to keep the engine running rich when you upgrade to forced induction. Running lean can cause the engine to fail. A good turbo for this vehicle would be a Mitsubishi TD-04 like what is found on the WRX. It's small but has large potential and quick spool. This would be more than enough air for the OEM Tata Nano.

As Juann said, any gain on such a small engine is going to be a small gain in the overall scheme of things. Although, if you gain 1-2hp from a single upgrade, overall it would be a big gain as compared to where you start at (2hp gain from stock is over a 5% gain). The turbo is going to be the best way to go to get the bigger gains. As a rule of thumb, for every 14 lbs of boost (psi), you will double the power output of the engine (if the engine can support that much power). I'm not suggesting you boost to that level, but if you bring it up to 7psi, you should see a gain of around 20hp which would bring a lot of vroom to your little go buggy. Of note, with a turbo, there is a lot of planning, fabrication, and support mods you'll have to do to make it work. Supporting mods are things like tuning, exhaust, and possibly drivetrain (can the transmission take the extra power??).

Something else you can look at, is whether you can transplant an engine from one of the other Tata models into your Nano. I don't know how things are in India (where the Nano is manufactured), but here in the States auto manufacturers utilize the same engine to transmission mounting arrangement between different engines to make things easier and to reduce production costs.

As far as styling, there are some body kits out there which you may like. [Here is one](http://www.autoamplified.com/the-dc-nano-bang-for-the-buck/) which might give you some ideas.

[image: Tata Nano]

I think this kit gives the Nano some aggressiveness you might be looking for, but it's up to you whether you like it or not. All I'm saying is, there are options out there for you. Do some research on the internet and you'll find something. If not, come up with your own modifications and make it happen.

Comment: I must say that I was impressed to learn the Tata Nano uses Bosch fuel injectors and management. It's practically the same management system I have in my 250+hp Astra Turbo.

Comment: As you stated, though, will a Nano engine be able to handle that much power? I would bet not, lol. My money is on self destruct :D

Comment: And while that's happening, Bon Jovi will be singing Blaze of Glory.